# Determining Time Based on Arc Seconds

Tags: the-sun, orbit, astrophysics, time

So our arc day starts at 20°41'32 which is midnight (0:00) and ends 24 hours later at 21°42'42. According to my calculations it traveled 0 degrees, 59 minutes, and 30 seconds or 3570 arc seconds in 24 hours. What I am looking for is, what time it will reach 21°15'30.32. For the love of God I have a brain freeze on how to get this.

This is what I came up with:

```
3570 arcseconds / 24 hours = 148.75 arcseconds/hour
1758.32 arcseconds / 148.75 arcseconds/hour ≈ 11.82 hours
```

but I do not think its accurate as the time I am looking for is 13:19:43.

Comment: The difference betwee 21°15'30.32 and 20°41'32 is 21*3600+15*60+30.32- (20*3600+41*60+32) = 2038.32 arcseconds.  Not 1758.32 arcseconds.

Comment: Try converting those angles to decimal degrees first.

Comment: 21.7117−20.6922=1.0195  which makes my arcseconds also wrong as it comes to 3682.2 arcseconds

Comment: 1.0195° = 3670″. Are you doing the arithmetic by hand?

Comment: online calculator... got it now, thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there doesn't appear to be an astronomical problem, only difficulty using an online calculator to calculate sexagesimal.

Comment: this conversation helped me <3 so thank you everyone, I wanted to know, are there other ways to determine the time ?

Comment: A good clock is often effective !